# Find text in a webpage using address bar command?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer

Is it possible in some web browser / all web browsers to navigate to a URL and find the first occurrence of text on the corresponding web page with a single string input to the address bar?  Essentially I want to omit the intervening "ctrl+F" and instead just append the text to search to the URL right in the address bar, presumably following some tag that signals a find text within webpage query.  Ideally I could use this to add web page links to documents that take the user straight to the relevant view, instead of to what might be a very long page containing a sentence or paragraph of interest that the user will have to scroll or navigate to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not finding (or know of) anything that does *exactly* what you're asking for. This sounds like plugin or scripting territory (e.g. something like [this](http://tobbot.com/en/modules/url-find-text-regexp/), but I cannot vouch for this program specifically), and you're asking for a native browser view. There's also the issue of which occurrence of the search text you want the page to display (first match, third match, n-th match).

If you just want to get to a certain section of a webpage, you'll notice you can specify the header with `#SectionName` as in the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Searching_from_a_web_browser#Firefox where the "#Firefox" specifies to go straight to the "Firefox" header/section of the same page (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Searching_from_a_web_browser).

Comment: Good point re which occurrence - I was thinking of the first occurrence without specifying it.  It would be useful where you have something that is not tagged as a header in the html but is some kind of unique section heading like "1.17(b)(A)(ii)" or similar.

Comment: Can you not make those section headings act in a similar fashion to headers? Or make them headers/subheaders themselves? You'll notice the following link does this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_technology#Excite (note: from the table of contents at the top of the page, this is organized as a subheader, but still exhibits the same behavior as a header because of how the page is written).

Comment: "how the page is written" - specifically the hashtag # seems to signal an "id" attribute of an html element.  In the Wikipedia links mentioned in this thread "Firefox" is the id attribute of the element containing the header "Firefox," and "Excite" is the id attribute of the element containing the header "Excite."  However I am thinking of cases where I am linking to a third-party web page and want to take someone to the specific header, so if the one I want doesn't have an "id" attribute, looks like I am out of luck.